# How to prevent overlapping x ticks when plotting multiple time series that are measured in different dates?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a dataset with date_time, date, time, and a VALUE1 column that shows measurement values of each time point. For the same ID, there are multiple measurements over a day. Besides, there are 6 different 24 hour measurements for an ID, which is shown in INSPECTION column. When I would like to see multiple measurements all together overlaid (only the time in x-axis without date info and VALUE1 on the y axis), the plots looks quite messy. #
As you can see x-axis is overlappin and does not look nice. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggqbo.png)
Below, you can find the sample data and my attempt in the commented part at the end before fig.show part.:

```py
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, dash_table, no_update
import plotly.graph_objects as go
random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME': pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-06 23:00:00', freq='20min'),
                   'ID': [random.randrange(1, 3) for n in range(430)]})
df['VALUE1'] = [random.uniform(110, 160) for n in range(430)]
df['VALUE2'] = [random.uniform(50, 80) for n in range(430)]
df['INSPECTION'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.day
# df['INSPECTION'] = df['INSPECTION'].replace(6, 1)
# df['INSPECTION'] = df['INSPECTION'].replace(3, 1)

df['MODE'] = np.select([df['INSPECTION'] == 1, df['INSPECTION'].isin([2, 3])], ['A', 'B'], 'C')
df['TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.time
df['TIME'] = df['TIME'].astype('str')

df['TIMEINTERVAL'] = df.DATE_TIME.diff().astype('timedelta64[m]')
df['TIMEINTERVAL'] = df['TIMEINTERVAL'].fillna(0)


def to_day_period(s):
    bins = ['0', '06:00:00', '13:00:00', '18:00:00', '23:00:00', '24:00:00']
    labels = ['Nighttime', 'Daytime', 'Daytime', 'Nighttime', 'Nighttime']

    return pd.cut(
        pd.to_timedelta(s),
        bins=list(map(pd.Timedelta, bins)),
        labels=labels, right=False, ordered=False
    )


df['TIME_OF_DAY'] = to_day_period(df['TIME'])
df_monthly = df

# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ sns plot ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
df_id = df[df.ID==1]
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(14,8)})
#print(df_id.INSPECTION.unique())
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df_id, x ='TIME', y = 'VALUE1',
                  hue='INSPECTION', palette='viridis',
                  legend='full', lw=3)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(4))
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
plt.ylabel('VALUE1')
plt.xlabel('TIME')
plt.show()
```

I tried adding a new column for the x-axis TIME column as a categorical variable code, but it did not work.  How can I fix this issue? **My expectation** is to see all 6 inspections together shown nicely. on the x-axis, there should be TIME column and x ticks should not overlap, and on the y-axis, there should be the VALUE1 column .

Comment: Do you want to do this using `seaborn`? Or is another library ok? I see you have imported `plotly`

Comment: @artemis I want to do this using seaborn

Answer (score 1):

Increase the `ticker.MultipleLocator` value:

```
...
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
...
```

[image]

or even more:

```
...
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(12))
...
```

[image]

Comment: your answer works like a charm. But, how can I show a 24 hours day cycle on the x axis without repeating the time again? To articulate, Your x-axis starts at 00:40:00 and then it shows 00:00:00 again. Is there a way to deal with this too? I want to show only time from 00:00:00 until 23:59:00 on th x-axis without repeating time

Comment: You could try `from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator` and `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(np.arange()))` and plug and chug values till you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, [I think `plotly` is a better solution for this](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/), but here is an answer using Seaborn that should work. You mostly need to use [`Facetgrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html). In this example, we [set the context to "paper"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_context.html) and pass a dictionary to the rc parameter to set figure.autolayout to True. This allows Matplotlib to adjust the figure size to fit the x-axis labels without overlapping.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
sns.set(context="paper", rc={"figure.autolayout": True})


g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='INSPECTION', hue='ID', col_wrap=2, height=4)
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'TIME', 'VALUE1', lw=2)
g.set_axis_labels('Time', 'Value1')
g.add_legend(title='ID')

plt.show()
```

Comment: the values on the x-axis are still overlapping. How can I solve it?